# ID Divs in For Loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, duplicates

Working in Javascript. I'm trying to duplicate a div and name it dynamically in a fo. Neither of the following appear to work:

```
var origDiv = document.getElementById("outerSquare");
for (i=1; i<=4; ++i){
    newDiv = document.body.appendChild(origDiv.cloneNode(true));
//  newDiv.id = "block"+i;
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "block"+i);
}
```

Here's the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dmperkins74/5r01zyma/

Funny thing is, it appears to be only duplicating the div inside my "outerSquare". If I remove the attempt to reset the ID, it all fails. Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan P.

Comment: It is working ok, as i can see? What is problem?

Comment: Since it's duplicating "outerSquare" I should be getting 4 new red squares each with a red square in the middle. If you comment out the "setAttribute" line, it functions the way I'd expect, but currently, all I see aside from the original block on the right is 4 stacked black boxes.

Comment: This does what you’re asking it to do – which you can easily check using your browser’s developer tools. Only the styles defined for `#outerSquare` obviously don’t apply any more, because you changed the id. And the inner elements still all have the id `innerSquare`, because you did not change that one at all, so you end up with multiple elements with the same id, which you should avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes:

```
<div class="outerSquare">
<div class="innerSquare"></div>
</div>

var origDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("outerSquare")[0];

for (i=1; i<=4; ++i){
    newDiv = document.body.appendChild(origDiv.cloneNode(true));
    newDiv.style.left = i*40 +"px";
    newDiv.style.top = i*40 +"px";
//  newDiv.id = "block"+i;
   //newDiv.setAttribute("id", "block"+i);
}

origDiv.style.left = "200px";

block2.style.left = "400px";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5r01zyma/3/  No id duplication, no styling problems.

By changing ID, you can't apply old css styles. That was problem. P.S. Now you can add id's if you need it.

Comment: You just blew my mind. Didn't even know I could JUST have a class for a div. Man I've got a lot to learn. Thanks a bunch :)